# Why Can't I Remove HTML tags from string in PHP

Tags: php, html, string

I am working on an HTML validator for a project and I cannot seem to figure out why I can't remove a section from a string.

I am just trying to search through a string such as `"<head><title></title></head>"` and use str_replace or chop to remove something like `"</title>"`.

This should return the new string of `"<head><title></head>"`. However this doesn't work for me and I am not sure why.

EDIT: I also have to do this in the way I am trying as it is for a theory of computing class and I have to show a logical process of how it works.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $tagCount; $i++) { 

        //Get tag to remove
        $remove = getCloseTag($closeTags, 0, 0);

        //Show the tag being removed
        echo "<br>Remove: " . htmlspecialchars($remove) . "<br>";

        //Remove tag from list

        //This will fail
        //chop($closeTags, $remove);

        //This also fails
        str_replace($remove, "", $closeTags);

        //Output truncated list
        echo "closeTags: " . htmlspecialchars($closeTags) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Just use a parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the result of `str_replace()` back to the variable, it doesn't modify it in place.

```
$closeTags = str_replace($remove, "", $closeTags);
```